# Laravel/MySQL - Error on foreign key contraint & belongsToMany with joins

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-5.1

Framework: Laravel 5.1.28.

MySQL: 5.6.16

When migrating the `firemen` table or the `victims` table I receive: `General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint`. Even just creating a table with the column name `fireman_id` produces the same table, even if it's not a foreign key.

```
users
    id (char36, uuid)
    first_name (varchar, 60)
    last_name (varchar, 60)

firemen
    fireman_id (char36, uuid) - primary foreign which references(id) on (users)

victims
    victim_id (char36, uuid) - primary foreign which references(id) on (users)

fireman_victim
    fireman_id (char36, uuid) - foreign which references(fireman_id) on (firemen)
    victim_id (char36, uuid) - foreign which references(victim_id) on (victims)
```

1. The obvious, why is the error occuring?
2. How can I join the users table to get the name data when doing the following?

This is my Model:

```
public function victims()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Victim', 'fireman_victim', 'fireman_id', 'victim_id');
}
```

In my Controller:

```
$fireman = Fireman::first();

$fireman->victims();
```

I can do this but is there a simpler way(Eager Loading? belongsToManyThrough)?

```
$fireman->victims()->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'victims.victim_id')->select('first_name', 'last_name);
```

Comment: Please elaborate it little more, while for `user` relation you should create `user_id` as a `foreign key` in your desire table, and then make relationship in laravel with your desire table.